# I am new to django-mptt, I want to get the descendants of a particular node. I am creating a drug store

Tags: python

for example:
Hiv/Aids Medications is one of my categories. This particular category has sub-categories that I termed drug family and each drug family (which is a sub-category under Hiv/Aids category) has children.
My problem is to query all the drug family in a given category, and for each drug family in that category to also get the children of a particular drug family.

Here is a sample of my model:

```py
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank= True, related_name='children', db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='Rx', blank=True)
    Chemical = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank = True, default=None)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        level_attr = "mptt_level"
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('parent', 'slug'))
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```